# Paypal configuration into new account

Tags: paypal

I am facing security header error while integrating paypal, the paypal integration works fine with sandbox environment and credentials but it is not working with live.

Is there any specific configuration i need to make in paypal as i am using paypal apis for integration.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: 10002 - Security error - Security header is not valid is the exact error message

Comment: Can you put the screen shot of the security header error?

Comment: See if this helps: https://support.bigcommerce.com/questions/1150/What+does+%22Security+Header+is+Not+Valid+10002%22+for+PayPal+mean%3F

Comment: That error message would typically only show when the credentials are incorrect. Could you please double check that there's no extra space characters in the credentials and that you're using the credentials for the correct mode you're using (Live vs. Sandbox)?

Comment: Yes i have checked the credentials, they are fine and no space is there

Comment: If there are some kind of special characters, don't forget to properly escape them.

Comment: no special characters are there, for sandbox it works but when i use live credentials it doesn't i cant found out the reason.

Comment: As we don't have the exact problem so we can just help in random. Please read this: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/lifecycle/goingLive/ if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

That error message would typically only show when the credentials are incorrect.
Could you please double check that there's no extra space characters in the credentials and that you're using the credentials for the correct mode you're using (Live vs. Sandbox)?

If it is set to Sandbox mode, you must use your Paypal sandbox credentials. The live ones will not work in Sandbox mode.

That error message indicates that your API credentials aren't being accepted by PayPal.

```
Common causes:

1. You have your PayPal module configured to "Sandbox" but have not used Sandbox API credentials.

2. You have your PayPal module configured to "Live" but have not used Live API credentials.

3. You have mis-typed one or more API credentials entries, including but not limited to leaving trailing spaces.

4. You have deleted and/or recreated new API credentials in your PayPal account but have not copied those new credentials back to your store.
```

This link help you more ..

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/errorcodes/

Comment: can you please guide me how to and from where i can change the sandbox en to live. a help url will work as i am not able to find the setting of paypal mode selection from sanbox to live.

Comment: This link help you more understand sandbox/live https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/ebook/PP_Sandbox_UserGuide/overview.html

Comment: from where i can change the mode in paypal.com from sandbox to live?

Comment: Like this way when you are using sandbox type <form target="paypal" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post"> to change link to this link <form target="paypal" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">

Comment: This is the error we are getting

http://softprodigy.in/CMPnew/app/webroot/images/live.png
http://softprodigy.in/CMPnew/app/webroot/images/sandbox.png

Comment: can you please look at the following screenshots and provide your input or the cause of issue

Comment: I view your both images. First image get successfully ACK but in second image not getting Success ACK. I think you are using same credential in SandBox and Live also. I think remember both type of Paypal process must be same but their Credential always different when they account are type of Personal or Sales ,they both account credential are different for Sales and Personal also.

Comment: Ravish, I have used the different credentials for both accounts, is there any specific settings we need to made in paypal website.. or i am missing something .. This is getting me insane !!

Answer (score 0):

We are using different credential for paypal and sandbox.Please Review these links softprodigy.in/CMPnew/app/webroot/images/live.png softprodigy.in/CMPnew/app/webroot/images/sandbox.png